# Does pg_export_snapshot work across replicas?

Tags: postgresql, master-slave-replication, snapshot

This is probably of little importance, but it's possible in PostgreSQL to retrieve the transaction snapshot with pg_export_snapshot and restore it with set transaction to start a second transaction with the same level of visibility (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-transaction.html)).

I'm interested to know if that works on a hot-standby or is specific to a single server? Could you export a snapshot on the standby and then use it with set transaction on the master? I doubt it.

Comment: Don’t think you can run pg_export_snapshot on a replica: think it needs to be run within a transaction — which you can’t do on a replica.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I'm being sloppy with my terminology, by replica I mean hot standby, which does allow transactions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/hot-standby.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it, and it is not possible, because exported snapshots are not replicated.

Snapshots are persisted in the `pg_snapshots` subdirectory of the data directory, and you will see that they don't show up on the standby.

Comment: Thanks for testing that out!